# How to show ActionBar when exit full screen by swipe down?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

```
mContext.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

I am using the above codes to hide enter the full screen mode. It can be exited by swiping back, top or bottom. However, the Action Bar remains hidden, while the status bar and navigation bar appears (Picture 2).

How can I bring up the ActionBar ? Or detecting the "Exit" (Picture 3) event listener so that I can call the following to show ActionBar?

```
mContext.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        );
```

Due to design requirement, I can't use the touch listener to bring up the ActionBar() in this case.

[image]
[image]
[image]